# Jquery remove validation on all buttons or allow validation only on needed buttons

Tags: asp.net, button, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validation plugin in my .Net application and have many number of groups that has to be validated inside my pages. I am validating the groups using

```
$("#aspnetForm").validate().element("#elementname");
```

Now the problem is, i have many server side buttons that are mandatory in application, some of them are ajax enabled and others are normal. When i click any button in the page it is validating all the elements in the page, i want to overcome this. I know, by adding class "cancel", we can skip validation, still that is not enough in my case. For example, i have a captcha refresh button which can be refreshed number of times, in this case, validation is skipped only one time and in sub-sequent click, it is triggering validation again.

Please help me in removing all the validation trigger from buttons or to trigger validation only on particular buttons which have some classes , instead of adding cancel class to unrequired buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Validate plugin will automatically capture the `click` event of any button with `type="submit"` contained within the `<form>` tags.  The only way to stop this is to not use buttons with `type="submit"`.

```
<form>
    ....
    <button type="submit">button</button>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

DEMO of default behavior:  http://jsfiddle.net/EhGQ5/

---

Alternatively, you can change your buttons to `type="button"` and then manually capture the `click` of a specific button(s).  You can then trigger the validation manually with the [`.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).  In this example, only the second button will trigger validation.

```
<form>
    ....
    <button type="button">button</button>
    <input type="button" value="button" id="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // this initialization may happen automatically within your framework
    $('#myform').validation({  // normal initialization
        // rules & options
    });

    // manually trigger a validation test using a specific button
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        $('#myform').valid();  // trigger form validation test
    });

});
```

DEMO of manually triggered validation:  http://jsfiddle.net/EhGQ5/2/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this is not the way i am expecting, i know how to validate the form in onclick and to use the .valid option, and i am utilizing it in other ways. My aim is to avoid validation triggering in button clicks :(. As you mentioned initially, i cannot remove type=button, as i will need the same for triggering server side methods in .Net.

Comment: It is even enough to disable validation trigger for all the buttons in the page. As i can use the .valid method explicitly in needed  button click events..